# Creating a javascript map

Tags: javascript, node.js

I started learning JS, especially Node.js, around 5-6 months ago, I worked a lot with Discord.js library and have knowledge of other programming languages.

I want to create a kind of datastore using `Map()`, before I only created arrays of objects, Discord.js had a bunch of maps in use and it was a pleasure to use them.

My new goal is to create a little app using Electron, I need to save users and program lists in maps, for persistence I want to save them as JSON, if it's possible, here are some example data from my pre-created JSON user file:

```
"user": [
    {
        "name": "David",
        "currentProgram": "program1",
        "currentPhase": "C",
        "workout": [
            {
                "name": "Workoutname",
                "load": "10", 
                "units": "kg"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Markus",
        "currentProgram": "program2",
        "currentPhase": "A",
        "workout": []
    }
]
```

program file:

```
"program": [
    {
        "name": "program1",
        "phases": [
            {
                "name": "A",
                "cycles": [
                    {
                        "name": "day 1",
                        "exercises": [
                            {
                                "name": "workout1",
                                "set": 4,
                                "repetitions": 8
                            },
                            {
                                "name": "workout2",
                                "set": 4,
                                "repetitions": 8
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

My goal is to do something like this:

```
var user = require('./user.json');

user.get("David").currentProgram = "program2";
user.get("David").currentPhase = "A";

var phase = program.get("program1").phases.get("A")

console.log(user.get("David"));
```

Instead of using an array like shown in the JSON file, I would create a `Map()`.

I was searching for some information how to create a map the best way in my case. If anyone has good how to's for learning js, especially `Map()` I would appreciate that. The only thing I found is `array.map` or google maps but that differs from `Map()`.

Another goal is the separate the code into different files so that I have a sperate file with the construction of each map.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A small helper to create a Map:

```
 function toMap(array, prop){
   const map = new Map();
   for(const el of array) map.set(el[prop], el);
   return map;
}
```

Usable like this:

```
 const users = JSON.parse(require("fs").readFileSync('./user.json')).user;
 users.byId = toMap(users, "name");

 console.log( users.byId.get("jonas"));
```

Comment: Thanks for the function, is it possible to create a map in map? Because as shown above, I have the program with their names, each program has multiple phases and each phase has multiple cycles and also each cycle has a bunch of exercises (don't necessary need a map of exercises).

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem like you really need a `Map` for this. Since your indexes are strings, an ordinary object would do.

You can define a generic function for indexing an array:

```
const indexBy = (prop, arr) => arr.reduce(
    (idx, el) => { idx[el[prop]] = el; return idx; },
    {}
);
```

And then all you need to to to build your user map is:

```
let userMap = indexBy('name', userArray);
```

After which you can access your users like this:

```
userMap['David'].currentProgram = "Program 2";
```

To re-obtain your array for serialization, you can do:

```
let updatedUserArray = Object.values(userMap);
```

Runnable example:

```js
const indexBy = (prop, arr) => arr.reduce(
  (idx, el) => {
    idx[el[prop]] = el;
    return idx;
  }, {}
);

// sample data
let userArray = [{
    "name": "David",
    "currentProgram": "program1",
    "currentPhase": "C",
    "workout": [{
      "name": "Workoutname",
      "load": "10",
      "units": "kg"
    }]
  },
  {
    "name": "Markus",
    "currentProgram": "program2",
    "currentPhase": "A",
    "workout": []
  }
];

let userMap = indexBy('name', userArray);

userMap['David'].currentProgram = "Program 2";
console.log(userMap['David']);
```

Comment: eslint expect a function declaration for the `indexBy` code, I tried it to convert it to a function style but I think I did something wrong.

    function indexBy(prop, arr) => {
        arr.reduce((idx, el) => {idx[el[prop]] = el; return idx;},
        {}
    )};

Can you also give me some description of this part? Most of them are clear to me, I read something about `.reduce()` but haven't used it ever.

Comment: @MarioFridrichovsky To express it as a function declaration, you need to put a `return` before the `arr.reduce`.